# Kendo UI color picker not showing the dialog to choose color

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to show a Kendo Color Picker when I click on a cell of a Kendo grid.

My actual code is much more complex and mostly generating during execution time. But, here is my code for editor for the a specific column of a Kendo Grid.

```
editor: function(container, options){ 
    var color = document.createElement('input');
    color.setAttribute('type', 'color');
    color.setAttribute('id', 'myColorField');
    container.show();
    $('#myColorField').appendTo(container).kendoColorPicker(
        {
            buttons: true
         }
    );
    }
```

I don't get any error, however, when I click on the cell to edit it, no color selection window is appearing. (only the text disappears on on-click of the cell.)
I am very new to Kendo UI. Could anyone please help about it?

Thanks!

Update:

I changed the code as below:

```
editor: function(container, options){ 
    var color = document.createElement('input');
    color.setAttribute('type', 'color');
    color.setAttribute('class', 'myColorField');
    container.show();
    $(this).find('.myColorField').appendTo(container).kendoColorPicker(
        {
            buttons: true
         }
    );
    }
```

Still no luck!

update: Alternate approach, still not working though!

```
editor: function(container, options){ 
  $("< input type = 'color' data-bind = 'value:" + prop.Name + "' /> " ).appendTo(container).kendoColorPicker({buttons: true});
}
```

update: Partially working code!

```
sb.Append(", editor: function(container, options){ " +
                                          "console.log(container);" +
                                           "$(\"< input name = '\"+options.field+\"' /> \" )" +
                                               ".appendTo(container)" +
                                               ".kendoColorPicker(" +
                                               "{" +
                                                   "buttons: true, " +
                                                   "value: options.model." + prop.Name+ "," +
                                                   "select: function(e) {" +
                                                        "options.model." + prop.Name + " = e.value" +
                                                   "}" +
                                               "}" +
                                           ");" +
                                       "}"
                                    );
```

I am now able to select the color from color picker and set it to the field I wanted. But, when I am trying to open this color picker, it looks weird and it show the data from  tag from the code above. I tried so many things, but, nothing worked!

[image]

update: There was an unintended space. The right code was this:

```
"$(\"<input name = '\"+options.field+\"' /> \" )"
```

instead of this:

```
"$(\"< input name = '\"+options.field+\"' /> \" )"
```

Comment: to start with, since it is within a grid try setting a class rather than an ID, you cannot have multiple elements with same Id

Comment: Thanks @Karthik, but, could you please provide some example? I am really new in Javascript.

Comment: Do you means something like this : color.setAttribute('class', 'myColorField');  $(this).find('.myColorField').appendTo(container).kendoColorPicker(
                                                    {
                                                        buttons: true
                                                     }
                                                );

Comment: @SrijaniGhosh I have updated the dojo so it should work correctly now. It seems that if you enable the colour pickers buttons this is where we hit some problems but without that the control works as expected.

Comment: @DavidShorthose, Thanks a lot! I will try and let you know. :)

Comment: @DavidShorthose, Thanks a lot. It works partially now :) . Please see the answer to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a simple dojo showing you a colour picker being added to a grid. 
https://dojo.telerik.com/aRUsUJOw

updated dojo: 
This one shows the colour stylized with the new colour being selected rather than just the  hex colour code.
https://dojo.telerik.com/aRUsUJOw/4

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now, I able to get the selected and set it into the grid. However, I am actually working  on a framework ( made and used  in my development team) which is based on Kendo UI and hence, I need to send the attributes to frameworks as a string buffer and I am facing now a problem. whenever I am click on the grid to open the color picker, I am seeing <input> tag text in the place where I should be seeing the color code. I will attach the current code and the result in the question itself. Again, Thanks!

Comment: see my updated dojo showing the text templated so the colour being selected is now colouring the text value. I think this is what you are after?

Comment: I saw the updated dojo. unfortunately it is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: without knowing more about how you are building your grid or what the expected `look` of it should be it is difficult to provide you with a better solution as the solution I have provided in the second dojo should work for most situations.

Comment: Yes, I understand that :( . I will try to provide more information.

Comment: Your solution worked. However, the problem was with an unintended space in the string which I am passing to the editor.